# how to achieve edmx drag scenario of database in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

**Hello** 
     I want to create  multiple div which have connectivity with each other with a lines,While dragging those divs, connections(i.e: Lines) should drag accordingly with div (** I want same structure  AS .edmx database file which shows in  .net project**).
 **

**I want This using Jquery only.**
Please Help me.

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jsplumb Community Edition or Toolkit edition](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos.html).

Pro-grammatically get your `Entities/Models` and add **jsplumb widgets** for each entitiy on the canvas with connections(lines).

They are very reliable with many addition functionality.

Additionally on Double-Clicking you can show the attrributes/paramenter of entities etc using **Dialogs/overlay/popup**.

You can also get different alternative for jsPlumb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233998/are-there-any-alternatives-to-jsplumb-for-the-purpose-of-connecting-dom-elemen)

---

**Update:** Links to learn jsPlumb:

---

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/gXuS7/)

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wGjDm/7/)

[Can read this also: ExtJs](https://balaslog.wordpress.com/category/jsplumb/)

[This one is good too Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Balagangadhar/N6nHp/)

---

Other than this read jsPlumb [documentation](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidn7KsnprKAhUVSY4KHSWDAlcQjBAIKzAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.jsfiddle.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNHzaP1OF_i1WDzjXp77HRsPLravmA&sig2=E87LjXRtKuPoJNntNeU97g) and [demos](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZlaS_n5rKAhXNW44KHdtPBqMQjBAIITAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjsplumbtoolkit.com%2Fdemos.html&usg=AFQjCNF3JOqFLdr07zBfADHpKLc0ggO7vw&sig2=DJ18hjGfHB0azEZTKY1wnA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.c2E)

Comment: Is there any other solution for that.??

Comment: I am not aware of it, you can use jQuery UI drag and drop and make your own widget connections, but using a plugin like jsPlumb will be recommended.

Comment: But JsPlumb is not free. And I want connection between multiple draggable divs

Comment: I am using jsPlumb community edition which is free and which has multiple draggable divs feature with path  and you download from here https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/download  or direct download link here: https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/lib/jsPlumb-2.0.5.js

Comment: Rohit : Hey I download the community version, But I am new in jquery, would you please give me some example how to use this community version. (example: Please create 2 or 3 div and applied "ANGULAR INTEGRATION" Demo on those div please.) Thanks in Advance. Rohit